# Copying linked objects along with animation

Tags: animation, armature

I am new to Blender and I managed to educate myself on how to animate objects.

I have animated how the module below gets deployed.

[image: Single module]

[image]

[image]

Using the same deployment strategy, the module needs to be multiplied to create a large formation like in the picture below.

[image: Full formation]

When I copy one module along with its animation, the animation fails to animate the copied module. At the end of first module animation, I want the second animation(copy of the module) to start. At the end of second, third starts and so on.... How can I execute this without manually creating animations for every module?

Comment: What is the way you are using here to animate the base module? (as it is mechanical there is not one possibility)

Comment: As the central connector is pulled up, the vertical and horizontal members loosen and collapse. I have added  2 images to show what I mean.